# Best practice for returning authenticated users in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I had a bit confusion in authentication, i'm a Laravel user since version 5.2. But in this scenario on version 5.6, I create a middleware that checks the authenticated users, the logout function was perfect but, i try to access the page with my middleware, it returns

```
Trying to get property 'name' of non-object
```

Because i had a function that fetches the name of Authenticated User.

How can i handle this scenario?

My Middleware code:

```
   public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    if (Auth::check()) {
     return $next($request);
    }
    return redirect()->route('login');
}
```

In the page:

```
{{Auth::user()->name}}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because the current user is not authenticated. You can use the [`optional()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-optional) helper:

```
{{ optional(auth()->user())->name }}
```

Or:

```
{{ auth()->check() ? auth()->user()->name : 'Please login' }}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering the question, but. I can access the page even if i unauthenticated

Comment: @RannieOllit well, it's not related to the question. Your question was about the error you've shown and this code fixes the error.